# OpenShift: Corn job script to backup mysql and email the backup file

Tags: openshift

I have a php application on openshift and I want to take backup of mysql db daily. I add the Cron cartridge. But I am new to corn job and less knowledge about scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mysqldump command to dump out the MySQL DB into a file. Then setup a cron job to run it every day.

Write a script to run the mysqldump and then put the script into /etc/cron.daily/ and it will run once per day.

Comment: Can I upload the script file via sftp ?
If yes which folder?

Comment: It depends on the server you're using. If it's a VPS will full SSH/root access, then use scp. If you're using shared hosting, then often, the host will provide access to cron jobs in their web interface

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out this blog post (https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-cron-jobs-on-openshift), which shows you how to get started with cron jobs on OpenShift gears.